# Cordova 3.0.0 Storage API error

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, web-sql, cordova-3

I'm developing crossplatform application, using cordova 3.0.0. The project is created using cordova-cli and built for android platform. It successfully using file and file-transfer plugins at the moment. The problem comes when attempting to use Storage API. According to PhoneGap documentation, [Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) is built into cordova since version 3.0. The problem is, when I'm trying to interact with Storage API

```
var db = window.openDatabase(name, "1.0", name, size);
```

Cordova's PluginManager logs error:

```
exec() call to unknown plugin: Storage
```

So, the question is: **Why does cordova tries to invoke Storage via PluginManager?**

Also posting my **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.FileUtils" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
</widget>
```

and **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.isd.immersivereader" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ImmersiveReader" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

The version of cordova.js, I'm using is 3.0.0-0-ge670de9 (as far as I know it's a head revision) and it does have Storage defenition.

If more information is required - just let me know).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Cordova >=3.0.0, you need to add the storage feature to your config.xml (app/res/xml/config.xml). E.g.

```
<feature name="Storage">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Note, this step is only necessary if you're not using the Command-line Interface.

Comment: I know the question is a bit odd. But can you give me the steps of adding a plugin to my project. [Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) says _As of version 3.0, access to Storage APIs is built into Cordova, and does not require using the CLI to add plugins as described in The Command-line Interface._ An yet you suggest to add the `feature` node in the `config.xml`. Please tell me the steps.